# Is there a way to load html generated with javascript in a specific div?

Tags: javascript, php, html, onload

I have a javascript function that generates some html content.
However the event listener i'm using load the content at the end of the page.*I'd like it to be loaded in a specific div.

```
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    createForm(<?php echo json_encode($training_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>);
});
```

I also tried the onload attribute in the div ... but stll doesn't work:

```
<div id="bdd"onload="createForm(<?php echo json_encode($training_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>);"></div>
```

The createForm function:

```
function createForm(arr){

    ct++;
    de++;
    na++;

    const form = document.getElementById("formed");
    const divi = document.getElementById("bdd");
    arr.forEach(element => {   
        const a = element.training_diploma;
        const b = element.training_school;
        const c = element.training_level;
        const d = element.training_start_date;
        const e = element.training_end_date;

        const training_diploma = document.createElement('input');
        training_diploma.setAttribute('value', a)
        training_diploma.setAttribute('name','saved_training['.concat(ct,'][training_diploma]'))
        training_diploma.required = true

        const training_school = document.createElement('input');
        training_school.setAttribute('value', b)
        training_school.setAttribute('name','saved_training['.concat(ct,'][training_school]'))
        training_school.required = true

        const divSelect = document.createElement('div');
        divSelect.setAttribute('class', 'select')

        const training_level = document.createElement('select');
        training_level.setAttribute('value', c)
        training_level.setAttribute('id', 'rec_mode')
        training_level.setAttribute('name','saved_training['.concat(ct,'][training_level]'))
        training_level.required = true  

            const option1 = document.createElement('option');
            option1.disabled = true
            option1.innerHTML='-- Type de diplôme --';

            const option2 = document.createElement('option');
            option2.innerHTML='Formation' 
            if (option2.innerHTML == c) {
                option2.selected = true
            } 

            const option3 = document.createElement('option');
            option3.innerHTML='Brevet'
            if (option3.innerHTML == c) {
                option3.selected = true
            } 
            const option4 = document.createElement('option');
            option4.innerHTML='Bac'
            if (option4.innerHTML == c) {
                option4.selected = true
            } 
            const option5 = document.createElement('option');
            option5.innerHTML='Bac +1'
            if (option5.innerHTML == c) {
                option5.selected = true
            } 
            const option6 = document.createElement('option');
            option6.innerHTML='Bac +2'
            if (option6.innerHTML == c) {
                option6.selected = true
            } 
            const option7 = document.createElement('option');
            option7.innerHTML='Bac +3'
            if (option7.innerHTML == c) {
                option7.selected = true
            } 
            const option8 = document.createElement('option');
            option8.innerHTML='Bac +4'
            if (option8.innerHTML == c) {
                option8.selected = true
            } 
            const option9 = document.createElement('option');
            option9.innerHTML='Bac +5'
            if (option9.innerHTML == c) {
                option9.selected = true
            } 

            const option10 = document.createElement('option');
            option10.innerHTML='Doctorat'
            if (option10.innerHTML == c) {
                option10.selected = true
            } 

        const training_start_date = document.createElement('input');
        training_start_date.setAttribute('type', 'month')
        training_start_date.setAttribute('value', d)
        training_start_date.setAttribute('name','saved_training['.concat(ct,'][training_start_date]'))
        training_start_date.required = true

        const training_end_date = document.createElement('input');
        training_end_date.setAttribute('type', 'month')
        training_end_date.setAttribute('value', e)
        training_end_date.setAttribute('name','saved_training['.concat(ct,'][training_end_date]'))
        training_end_date.required = true

        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('id', 'row-'+ct++)
        div.setAttribute('class', 'training_container')

        const del = document.createElement('a');
        del.setAttribute('href','javascript:removeSavedTraining('.concat(de++,')'))
        del.setAttribute('class','remove_button')
        del.innerHTML='- Supprimer cette formation'
        

        form.appendChild(divi);
        divi.appendChild(div);
        div.appendChild(training_diploma);
        div.appendChild(training_school);
        div.appendChild(divSelect);
        divSelect.appendChild(training_level);
            training_level.appendChild(option1);
            training_level.appendChild(option2);
            training_level.appendChild(option3);
            training_level.appendChild(option4);
            training_level.appendChild(option5);
            training_level.appendChild(option6);
            training_level.appendChild(option7);
            training_level.appendChild(option8);
            training_level.appendChild(option9);
            training_level.appendChild(option10);                
        div.appendChild(training_start_date);
        div.appendChild(training_end_date);
        div.appendChild(del);
    });
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    createForm(<?php echo json_encode($training_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>);
});
```

Any idea ? Thanks a lot from France !

Comment: You don't share the `createForm` function - but this appears to be key to this. It either doesn't do what you need (I don't know if you wrote it, if so then obviously you can change it so it works as you need), or you haven't called it correctly.

Comment: @RobinZigmond i've just added the function to the question ! thanks for your advice !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer !

basically, as everyone said, a "return" was missing ! Just needed to figure out where to place !

```
function createForm(arr){

ct++;
de++;
na++;

const form = document.getElementById("formed");
const divi = document.getElementById("bdd");
arr.forEach(element => {   
    const a = element.training_diploma;
    const b = element.training_school;
    const c = element.training_level;
    const d = element.training_start_date;
    const e = element.training_end_date;

    const training_diploma = document.createElement('input');
    training_diploma.setAttribute('value', a)
    training_diploma.setAttribute('name','saved_training['.concat(ct,'][training_diploma]'))
    training_diploma.required = true

    const training_school = document.createElement('input');
    training_school.setAttribute('value', b)
    training_school.setAttribute('name','saved_training['.concat(ct,'][training_school]'))
    training_school.required = true

    const divSelect = document.createElement('div');
    divSelect.setAttribute('class', 'select')

    const training_level = document.createElement('select');
    training_level.setAttribute('value', c)
    training_level.setAttribute('id', 'rec_mode')
    training_level.setAttribute('name','saved_training['.concat(ct,'][training_level]'))
    training_level.required = true  

        const option1 = document.createElement('option');
        option1.disabled = true
        option1.innerHTML='-- Type de diplôme --';

        const option2 = document.createElement('option');
        option2.innerHTML='Formation' 
        if (option2.innerHTML == c) {
            option2.selected = true
        } 

        const option3 = document.createElement('option');
        option3.innerHTML='Brevet'
        if (option3.innerHTML == c) {
            option3.selected = true
        } 
        const option4 = document.createElement('option');
        option4.innerHTML='Bac'
        if (option4.innerHTML == c) {
            option4.selected = true
        } 
        const option5 = document.createElement('option');
        option5.innerHTML='Bac +1'
        if (option5.innerHTML == c) {
            option5.selected = true
        } 
        const option6 = document.createElement('option');
        option6.innerHTML='Bac +2'
        if (option6.innerHTML == c) {
            option6.selected = true
        } 
        const option7 = document.createElement('option');
        option7.innerHTML='Bac +3'
        if (option7.innerHTML == c) {
            option7.selected = true
        } 
        const option8 = document.createElement('option');
        option8.innerHTML='Bac +4'
        if (option8.innerHTML == c) {
            option8.selected = true
        } 
        const option9 = document.createElement('option');
        option9.innerHTML='Bac +5'
        if (option9.innerHTML == c) {
            option9.selected = true
        } 

        const option10 = document.createElement('option');
        option10.innerHTML='Doctorat'
        if (option10.innerHTML == c) {
            option10.selected = true
        } 

    const training_start_date = document.createElement('input');
    training_start_date.setAttribute('type', 'month')
    training_start_date.setAttribute('value', d)
    training_start_date.setAttribute('name','saved_training['.concat(ct,'][training_start_date]'))
    training_start_date.required = true

    const training_end_date = document.createElement('input');
    training_end_date.setAttribute('type', 'month')
    training_end_date.setAttribute('value', e)
    training_end_date.setAttribute('name','saved_training['.concat(ct,'][training_end_date]'))
    training_end_date.required = true

    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('id', 'row-'+ct++)
    div.setAttribute('class', 'training_container')

    const del = document.createElement('a');
    del.setAttribute('href','javascript:removeSavedTraining('.concat(de++,')'))
    del.setAttribute('class','remove_button')
    del.innerHTML='- Supprimer cette formation'
    

    form.appendChild(divi);
    divi.appendChild(div);
    div.appendChild(training_diploma);
    div.appendChild(training_school);
    div.appendChild(divSelect);
    divSelect.appendChild(training_level);
        training_level.appendChild(option1);
        training_level.appendChild(option2);
        training_level.appendChild(option3);
        training_level.appendChild(option4);
        training_level.appendChild(option5);
        training_level.appendChild(option6);
        training_level.appendChild(option7);
        training_level.appendChild(option8);
        training_level.appendChild(option9);
        training_level.appendChild(option10);                
    div.appendChild(training_start_date);
    div.appendChild(training_end_date);
    div.appendChild(del);
});
 return divi;
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    document.getElementById("training").appendChild(createForm(<?php echo json_encode($training_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `element.innerHTML` to do this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `docuemnt.getElementById` and `innerHTML` should do the trick.

```js
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "Your content here";
```

```html
<!-- The element where you want the text -->
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks anis for your reply ! how can I combine innerHTML and a function then ?
I tried this but still doesn't work. Sorry i'm a noob at js ...

`    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
        document.getElementById("bdd").innerHTML = createForm(<?php echo json_encode($training_array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>);
    });`

Comment: Yes, you can do exactly that, if your function `createForm` returns HTML. @HymedGhenai

Comment: And nothing to be sorry for. We all start somewhere ;)

Comment: It doesn't seem that my function returns html (see in question). I also tried appendChild ans createElement, but succesless. How can I know the type of the result of my function ?